# segment a string to many strings given a pattern in php

Tags: php

I'm stuck and I just need a pointer.
I have this string with special characters retrieved from db and i want to segment it to many strings or arrays and in the process i want to exchange those characters with "()". 
|p| stands for parent. |c| child.

Example sentence is :

```
my beautiful car is awesome
```

*where my , beautiful and car have a parent-child relationship.

The pattern for it :

```
|p|my|c||p|beautiful|c||c||p|car|p|is|p|awesome
```

In case you need to see the original array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => |p|my
        [parent_id] => 0
        [child] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => |c||p|beautiful
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [child] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => |c||c||p|car
                                        [parent_id] => 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => |p|is
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => |p|awesome
        [parent_id] => 0
    )

)
```

The ultimate goal after segmenting and replacement is:
((My(beautiful(car)) (is)(awesome))

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do?  Turn the pattern into an array?  Or the array into a string?  You speak of substituting brackets `()`, where?

Comment: I guess your special characters from the db would be better described as tokens.

Comment: I edited see the last line please.

Comment: I just don't know how to begin to tackle this.

Comment: Probably mean: ((My(beautiful(car)))(is)(awesome))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$items =
[
    [
        'name'  => 'foo',
        'children' => 
            [
                [
                    'name'  => 'bar',
                    'children' => 
                        [
                            [
                                'name' => 'baz',
                            ]
                        ]
                ]
            ]
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'bat',
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'man',
    ]
];

function bracketize($array) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($array as $item) {
        $output .= '(';
        $output .=  $item['name'];
        if(isset($item['children']))
            $output .= bracketize($item['children']);
        $output .= ')';
    }

    return $output;
}

$output = '(' . bracketize($items) . ')';
print $output;
```

Output:

```
((foo(bar(baz)))(bat)(man))
```

Comment: Thank you Progrock for the effort you put in. This is exactly my aim. Building on Ruslan's argument i was experimenting with str_replace for the tokens. But this is closer to my purpose. I hope i didn't occupy your whole day.

Comment: @MK I'm working on a similar token problem, so the question piqued my interest.  Turns out your array was already in a form that was easy to use.  It's similar to  building a website navigation nested menu (list).  Ruslan in turn helped me.  Swings and roundabouts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you requested only a pointer I suggest to start with a regex to get an intermediate array:

```
$str = '|p|my|c||p|beautiful|c||c||p|car|p|is|p|awesome';
$res = preg_split('/((?:\|c\|)*\|p\|)/', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($res);

/*
array (
  0 => '|p|',
  1 => 'my',
  2 => '|c||p|',
  3 => 'beautiful',
  4 => '|c||c||p|',
  5 => 'car',
  6 => '|p|',
  7 => 'is',
  8 => '|p|',
  9 => 'awesome',
)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you . Now i know what to research.